# C# Regex to parse json-like top object

Tags: c#, regex

I need to parse json-like text file to extract objects like this with C# Regex:

```
foo {
    line1
    line2
}

bar {
    line3
    line4
}
```

i.e. objects that begins and ends at the begin of a line.
C# test code:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("\\n[^ \\n]+ \\{[.\\n]+\\n\\}");
string s = "\nfoo {\n    line1\n    line2\n}";
string v = regex.Match(s).Value;
```

it means:

> new line->anything except space and new line->" {"->any thing plus new line->new line->}

The expected result is just s. But the result is empty string.
If I remove `"\\n\\}"` at the end:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("\\n[^ \\n]+ \\{[.\\n]+");
string s = "\nfoo {\n    line1\n    line2\n}";
string v = regex.Match(s).Value;
```

then `v="\nfoo {\n"`

this works as expected, so it seem that the problem comes from `"\\n\\}"`.

Comment: "Need an out of the box solution" -- wrong platform then, SO isn't a code writing service...

Comment: @ sticky bit  you know what I mean , the answer is only one line of code instead of a program. SO will be better if more people focus on answering question instead of use the law out of context.

Comment: parse and regex are total different things. Use/Write a parser for parsing

Comment: @ sticky bit and Sir Rufo:this is exactly what I mean by "out of the box solution". Non- out of the box solution won't solve the problem, but may create discussions that waste time. The reason here is that writing a parser e.g based on ANTLR may cost days for a new comer, here only one line of code is needed to solve the problem.

Comment: @Sir Rufo Indeed I use regex to preprocess the file to a standart json file, then use JSON.NET to parse it.

Comment: Perhaps `^\S+\s*{\n(?:(?!}).*\n)*}` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/F2UDBS/1/)

Comment: @Sir Rufo You are probably right, not I'v get into a nightmare because there are countless details to deal with...you can never produce a standard json...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your example data, you could match the first line ending with an opening curly brace.

Then use a repeating pattern to match the whole line  only if it does not start with a closing `}`. You could do that using a negative lookahead `(?!})`.

Then match the closing curly brace.

```
[\r\n]\S+\s*{[\r\n](?:(?!}).*[\r\n])*}
```

About the pattern

- `[\r\n]` Match newline
- `\S+\s*` Match 1+ times a non whitespace char, then 0+ times a whitespace char
- `{[\r\n]` Match opening `{` followed by a newline
- `(?:(?!})` Negative lookahead, assert what is directly on the right is not a `}`
- `.*[\r\n]` Match any char except a newline 0+ times, then match a newline
- `}` Match closing `}`

[.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5b%5cr%5cn%5d%5cS%2b%5cs*%7b%5b%5cr%5cn%5d%28%3f%3a%28%3f!%7d%29.*%5b%5cr%5cn%5d%29*%7d&i=%0d%0afoo+%7b%0d%0a++++line1%0d%0a++++line2%0d%0a%7d%0d%0a%0d%0abar+%7b%0d%0a++++line3%0d%0a++++line4%0d%0a%7d) | [C# demo](https://ideone.com/7huXDx)

For example:

```
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"^\S+\s*{[\r\n](?:(?!}).*[\r\n])*}"); 
        string s = @"foo {
    line1
    line2
}

bar {
    line3
    line4
}";

        Console.WriteLine(regex.Match(s).Value);
```

Result:

```
foo {
    line1
    line2
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a working example base on my above C# code? I try new Regex(@"^\S+\s*{\n(?:(?!}).*\n)*}") but still get empty string.

Comment: @jw_ I have updated my answer and added an example 
 using `[\r\n]` to match a newline https://ideone.com/6TKDBo

Comment: Please try it on my above string: string s = "\nfoo {\n    line1\n    line2\n}"; I still get empty string. Is it because of "\r"? My text file only contains "\n", not "\r\n".

Comment: Ah, If it should start with a newline, then change the `^` to ` \n` like https://ideone.com/awTfJF I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I find a working solution:

```
Regex r1 = new Regex("\\n[^ \\n]+ \\{[\\s\\S]+?\\n\\}");
string s = "\nfoo {\n    line1\n    line2\n}";
string v = r1.Match(s).Value;
```

now v="\nfoo {\n    line1\n    line2\n}"

I'm new to regular expressions, after more research, a reference says that when you put "." in "[]", the dot won't represent "anything" anymore. You can use "[\s\S]" to represent everything including new line.

Comment: I that case, if you have multiple items you might make the `[\s\S]+?` non greedy using a  `?` or else you would match more than you want, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/zWx1OE/1)

Comment: @The fourth bird  You are right, indeed I didn't test the above code (on foo+bar), I found this during another case.